# jit-grunt: Plugin for the "clean" task not found?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-usemin

when i run grunt build i got this error, any idea how can i resolve this issue ?

grunt build

```
Running "concurrent:dist" (concurrent) task
    Warning: 
    jit-grunt: Plugin for the "compass" task not found.
    If you have installed the plugin already, please setting the static mapping.
    See https://github.com/shootaroo/jit-grunt#static-mappings

    Warning: Task "compass:dist" failed. Use --force to continue.

    Aborted due to warnings.
```

Gruntfile.js

```
  require('jit-grunt')(grunt, {
    express: 'grunt-express-server',
    useminPrepare: 'grunt-usemin',
    ngtemplates: 'grunt-angular-templates',
    cdnify: 'grunt-google-cdn',
    protractor: 'grunt-protractor-runner',
    buildcontrol: 'grunt-build-control',
    istanbul_check_coverage: 'grunt-mocha-istanbul',
    ngconstant: 'grunt-ng-constant'
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the `compass` plugin as a dependency. You can achieve this by executing the below command from your working directory.

```
npm install grunt-contrib-compass --save-dev
```

Hope this helps!